# Deletion of more than one node link list at a time. 

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

I need to implement a dynamic array with link lists and delete more than on node when a certain condition is met. Say if the data part of the node is greater than a fixed value, delete that node.

Can I delete more than one node at one traverse of the list without returning to the head of the list and search for the next node to be deleted? Will I be able to do this with a doubly linked list? All I need to do is delete certain nodes on fulfillment of a condition and keep traversing the list further at the same time without returning to the head of the list.

Comment: THAT IS VERY INTERESTING BUT COULD YOU CONSIDER USING NORMAL CAPITALIZATION? IT'S AWFULLY LOUD IN HERE OTHERWISE

Comment: dynamic array is a different data structure then a linked list. what is it? Also, is it homeowrk?

Comment: Oh, this is the [second time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547658/deletion-of-node-link-list) already. Please stop asking all caps questions. If you repeat this, you will eventually be banned from asking questions.

Comment: I've fixed your all-caps question. Please do yourself and everybody else a favor and properly format your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting elements from anywhere in a doubly linked list is generally no problem. Obviously, what you *can't* do is to move along the list from an element you've just removed - it's no longer part of the list. The trick is holding on to a valid reference to an item in your list while you traverse it. Since you've provided no code, I'll give an example using the STL `std::list` and its iterators:

```
std::list<int> mylist;
mylist.push_back(1);
mylist.push_back(2);
mylist.push_back(3);
mylist.push_back(4);

// now we want to remove elements 2 and 4
std::list<int>::iterator current = mylist.begin();
// current: item 1
++current;
// current: item 2
mylist.erase(current); // remove item 2
++current; // BUG! the iterator is invalid after removing the item it references
```

instead:

```
std::list<int>::iterator current = mylist.begin();
// current: item 1
++current;
// current: item 2
std::list<int>::iterator next = current;
++next; // move 'next' to item 3
mylist.erase(current); // remove item 2
current = next; // make current point to item 3
++current;
// current: item 4
mylist.erase(current); // remove item 4
```

This isn't specific to STL linked lists (or C++ for that matter) - instead of an iterator you might have a pointer to an element instead, but it's the same principle.

Comment: I don't program in C++ much, but I can see now why C++11 introduced `auto`.

Comment: @svick most of the time you end up `typedef`ing the collection and iterator types in pre-C++11 code: `typedef std::list<int> int_list; typedef std::list<int>::iterator int_list_it;`. `auto` is very useful for some of the gnarlier nested template types, though.

Comment: @pmjordan..thanx...i m using a structure of the form struct{

Comment: @codedmaverik if you have code to share, I suggest you update the question.